# Can I launch a trigger on select statement in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I am trying to run an `INSERT` statement on table X each time I `SELECT` any record from table Y is there anyway that I can accomplish that using MySQL only?

Something like triggers?

Comment: Short answer is **No**. Triggers are triggered with `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE`.

Comment: Updating every row on a select would cause performance headaches for bulk operations.  Best to specifically update a last_accessed timestamp for operations where it makes sense to do so.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Short answer is No. Triggers are triggered with `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE`.

Possible solution for this. rather rare scenario:

- First, write some stored procedures
  that do the `SELECT`s you want on
  table X.
- Then, restrict all users to use only
  these stored procedures and do not
  allow them to directly use `SELECT` on table
  X.
- Then alter the stored procedures to
  also call a stored procedure that
  performs the action you want
  (`INSERT` or whatever).

Comment: I'd like to quibble with the "_weird_" characterization. Specifically, if one is accessing controlled information (_e.g. labels for manufacturing_) where we want to control the number of times a document stored in the DB is accessed or printed, this is exactly a feature I want.
If information control is wrong (_weird_), I don't want to be right.

Comment: @DannyHolstein ok, "weird" was not the best choice. Does "rare" sound better?

Comment: I should put in a feature request for that ability.

Comment: I tried to implement the solution with a VIEW and stored function, when trying to do an INSERT into the table that tracks access, it can't, because that table is already open and is locked.

Comment: @DannyHolstein you can post a new question with your implementation and the issue that happens (and add a link to this one).

Answer (score 5):

Nope - you can't trigger on SELECT - you'll have to create a stored procedure (or any other type of logging facility - like a log file or what ever) that you implicitly call on any query statement - easier if you create a wrapper that calls your query, calls the logging and returns query results.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to use table X to log the order of `SELECT` queries on table Y (a fairly common query-logging setup), you can simply reverse the order of operations and run the `INSERT` query **first**, *then* run your `SELECT` query.

That way, you don't need to worry about linking the two statements with a `TRIGGER`: if your server crashes between the two statements then you already logged what you care about with your first statement, and whether the `SELECT` query runs or fails has no impact on the underlying database.

If you're not logging queries, perhaps you're trying to use table Y as a task queue -- the situation I was struggling with that lead me to this thread -- and you want whichever session queries Y first to lock all other sessions out of the rows returned so you can perform some operations on the results and insert the output into table X. In that case, simply add some logging capabilities to table Y.

For example, you could add an "owner" column to Y, then tack the `WHERE` part of your `SELECT` query onto an `UPDATE` statement, run it, and then modify your `SELECT` query to only show the results that were claimed by your `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE Y SET owner = 'me' WHERE task = 'new' AND owner IS NULL;
SELECT foo FROM Y WHERE task = 'new' AND owner = 'me';
```

...do some work on foo, then...

```
INSERT INTO X (output) VALUES ('awesomeness');
```

Again, the key is to log **first**, then query.

Comment: Kinda, but I'm restricted in using multiple  lines. This is a dumb printer driver which will only look at views. I did come up with a workaround to retire entries at scheduled intervals, but I found more bugs in the Bradly printer software that makes it completely unusable, and no one there wants to fix it.