# Maximum hits on a table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, usage-statistics

I need to do some analysis of table usage within my MySQL system. Can anyone point me in the right direction on a method for identifying *which table has been queried most often* in a given time-period i.e. if there are 30 tables, I want to know which table is accessed most.

Comment: Please specify...  Maybe you mean  '... table that is read the _most_...'   Also it is quite difficult to know what you mean by 'maximum hits on a table' ?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/q/6137935/384155

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [pt-table-usage](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-table-usage.html) to analyze the [general query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-log.html). It will out put nice information about table usage (as long as you're not using stored procedures or stored functions cause those will be missed).

Comment: is it free to use or paid?

Comment: It's free and open source.

Comment: I have not used this percona tool before but I will study on this. I am still wondering why my question has been closed and down-voted!

Answer (score 0):

Enable [query logging](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-log.html) temporarily while your application is running and review the log. It can have some performance impact, so you don't want to leave it permanently enabled.

Comment: Weird? Why did this get a down vote?

Comment: You are welcome. I'm not sure why your question was closed, either. Andreas's recommendation of the percona-toolkit is a good one.