# trigger before select

Tags: mysql, select, triggers

I have the following trigger statement

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER rating
BEFORE SELECT
ON `clinic`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.OLD.`rate` = (SELECT AVG(`rate`) FROM `Review` WHERE `Clinic_id` = NEW.OLD.`id`);
END//
```

I tried to follow the instructions given here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html but getting syntax error. What am I doing wrong?

NB I have run the `SELECT` statement on `Review` table and it gives result without any problem.

Edited: I realized that I can't have a trigger before `SELECT` and therefore decided to handle that on the application layer. See this: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?99,277396,277692#msg-277692

Comment: You can't put a trigger on a SELECT. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137935/can-i-launch-a-trigger-on-select-statement-in-mysql

Comment: haha, wow! I read almost the whole thing in that link and didn't notice SELECT wasn't a **trigger_event**! So what do you suggest I can do?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve. Check how much a clinic is 'seen' on average?

Comment: after seeing this [trigger after select](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?99,277396,277692#msg-277692) I think I should just do the averaging on the application side.

Comment: Yeah you can just copy paste this SELECT and use it as a sub-query.

Answer (score 3):

trigger_event can not be a select trigger_event = { INSERT | UPDATE | DELETE }

```
CREATE
[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]
TRIGGER trigger_name
trigger_time trigger_event
ON tbl_name FOR EACH ROW
trigger_body
```

trigger_time: { BEFORE | AFTER }

trigger_event: { INSERT | UPDATE | DELETE }