# Mysql: Restricting a row to read only one time

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table like below;

*CUSTOMMERS table:

IDcustomer, cname, cadress, readedToProcess, .....*

For execution a critical process, 400 client/pc is working on this table. Each client/pc is reading next customer which is not processed yet. And execute the process...  EACH CUSTOMER MUST NOT BE READED(PROCESSED) MORE THAN ONE TIME. This is very important.

The table has about 1 million records. There is almost 1 read/process per second. I am using readedToProcess field for this purpose. When I read a customer record, I instantly update readedToProcess to 1... While reading next record, I am checking readedToProcess field first, if it is not 1, I read. But this not solve my problem. A client/pc readed a customer record, other client/pc may read the same record, before first client/pc update readedToProcess field to 1... Yes read and update time is very low to dublicate read but its occuring.  10 - 100 dublicate read/process is appear after all customers processed (finished)

**I must restrict each customer record to read only one time..** (this table is not using for other goals)

How can I solve this problem? Is it possible to update readedToProcess field to 1, while I read the row, IN THE SAME QUERY... If its possible could you write the sql query for the table above....

Or what you recommend?

Thank you very much,

sorry for my bad english...

Comment: Your English is fine. Your question, on the other hand, seems like a rambling train of thought without anything that's actionable.

Comment: dear @tadman, this is a real and big problem for me.. :( thank you

Comment: Bottom line - don't use relational database for saving work queues. As you can see, they're not really fit for that, especially when you add concurrency to the list.

Comment: dear @N.B. so what modification do you recommend?

Comment: My suggestion would be looking into a job queue for your language of choice.

Comment: This is out of question... Thank you... There is good recommendation below to solve this problem

Comment: someone must be idiot. this is REAL question... look at my solution below. look at internet how many people dealing with the same case. :(.. how can you mark this question as "not a real question". its unbelievable.....

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure if I understood you right, my english is not on the best side either.

Anyway, I'd like to mention that a stored procedure bound on a SELECT of a row might be your way to update the readedToProcess value. unfortunately, triggers cant be bound to selects - see [can i launch a trigger on select statement in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137935/can-i-launch-a-trigger-on-select-statement-in-mysql)

Doesn't sound like future-proof design, though..

Answer (score 1):

i think you will need some read locking as in this article:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

In some circumstances, a consistent (nonlocking) read is not convenient and a locking read is required instead. InnoDB supports two types of locking reads:

SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE sets a shared mode lock on the rows read. A shared mode lock enables other sessions to read the rows but not to modify them. The rows read are the latest available, so if they belong to another transaction that has not yet committed, the read blocks until that transaction ends.

For index records the search encounters, SELECT ... FOR UPDATE blocks other sessions from doing SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE or from reading in certain transaction isolation levels. Consistent reads will ignore any locks set on the records that exist in the read view. (Old versions of a record cannot be locked; they will be reconstructed by applying undo logs on an in-memory copy of the record.)

Locks set by LOCK IN SHARE MODE and FOR UPDATE reads are released when the transaction is committed or rolled back.

Comment: dear @Randy, I read the mysql page and your answer. It seems that you catch the solution but its very confusing for me. could you write me the simple sql query for this.... thank you very much...

Comment: here is my solution...
when a workstation send this query to mysql server;
SELECT cname, cadress FROM `CUSTOMMERS` WHERE readedToProcess not like '%1%'  FOR UPDATE;
all other workstations (which want to query related rows) are waiting for first workstation to complate update query.

Comment: after first workstation update (set readedToProcess = '1') and close the connection (if first workstations connection will not close, "commit;" command must send to server after update query), other workstations waiting queries complete...

Comment: Note: workstations must run the query below, after connection before sending "FOR UPDATE" query...
SET autocommit=0;

Answer (score 0):

One other idea:

create a new table - with the column of the primary key that you are updating in the first table only.

each workstation reads the row it thinks it wants to work on, then inserts that into this new table.

if the insert works, then ok, if the insert fails with UNIQUENESS violation (from a unique index) then you should not proceed.

Comment: great idea... you mean I can update before I process related customer (now I am updating the field after proces so duplicate process may occur)... isn't it? if update is fail (updated yet) do not use this customer to process...

Comment: i mean INSERT in another table - instead of your current idea of UPDATE all in one table.