# sql current date constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I need to add a constraint to one table in my database. The table name is Experience. And there is a column named ToDate. Every time the select statement executes like following.

```
select ToDate from Experience
```

It should return current date.

So every time select statement executes, the ToDate column get updated with current date.

I know I can do this with some type of sql trigger but is there a way to do it by sql constraint.

like

```
alter table add constraint...
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just run `SELECT GETDATE()` ?

Comment: @jiggsJedi yes I can, I can also do it with trigger. But I like to know can I do this with sql constraint

Comment: FYI: Triggers cannot be fired by `SELECT` statements.  Triggers are fired by modification statements (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`).  This true in SQL Server and AFAIK in most other SQL implementations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx#TsqlProcedure).  That's specified like `colname as <expression>`:

```
create table t1(id int, dt as getdate());
insert t1 values (1);
select * from t1;
```

Comment: +1: For completeness, the same effect can also be accomplished with Views or table-valued Functions.

Answer (score 1):

To add contraint ...

```
create table tbl (id int identity, dt datetime, colval varchar(10))


ALTER TABLE dbo.tbl
ADD CONSTRAINT col_dt_def
DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR dt;
```

Example of inserting to the table ..

```
insert into dbo.tbl(colval)
select 'somevalue'

select * from dbo.tbl
```

The result will be ..

```
id  dt  colval
1   2014-08-19 13:31:57.577 somevalue
```

Comment: A default constraint is only used for new rows, when the column is not explicitly inserted.  The value stored will not change over time.

Comment: @Andomar .. Yes that is correct. Not sure if the OP needs to update the existing records.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a constraint, because a constraint is basically a rule on what can go in the table, how the table can relate to others, etc. It has no bearing on the data in the table once it goes into the table. Now if I am understanding you correctly, you want to update the `ToDate` column whenever you select that column. Now you can't use a trigger either as mentioned [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1556647?tstart=0) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137935/can-i-launch-a-trigger-on-select-statement-in-mysql). They suggest a stored procedure where you would use an `update` followed by an `insert`. This is probably my preferred SQL method to go with if you have to use it repeated, which you seem to have to do. Though Andomar's answer is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link code make help full

http://www.sqlatoms.com/queries/how-to-use-the-getdate-function-in-sql-server-3/

```
CREATE TABLE ProductOrders
(
  OrderId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
  ProductName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
  OrderDate datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()
)
```