# Automatically Update Field on table

Tags: sql, triggers, conditional-statements

I have field endTime and status in table X

I want to check endTime value every I execute query

```
SELECT * FROM X
```

if **`endTime value == Current`** time then automatically **`update status = 1`**;

not necessary after execute select query. in any other way. the point is I want update status=1 when endTime =  current time.
could you give me an example how to make it on Trigger or else ? I'm newbie

Comment: Tell us more about the problem you are trying to solve - perhaps a trigger isn't the right approach.

Comment: the point is i wawnt to automatically update status = 1 when endTime = current time. that's it.

Comment: You talk about wanting a select statement to trigger the update, what would trigger the select statement?

Comment: select *from x where status = 0;
so i want to show all data rent when it not end yet. for make it accurate, i think the best way is do something before select. so i ask how to update automatically when select statement is execute
that's why i need make it automatic update. it's not efficient if user have to reload page.

Comment: How about just having an update statement change the value before getting the data for the page?

Answer (score 0):

See [can i launch a trigger on select statement in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137935/can-i-launch-a-trigger-on-select-statement-in-mysql)

Looks like the short answer is you can't triggers for selects.

Comment: so, what the best way should i do ?

Comment: not necessary after execute select query. the point is I want to update status = 1 when endTime == current time. in any way.

Comment: You shouldn't even have a status field that has that functionality.  Just any time you query the table, make a column in your query that is that function.  So, like, select (endTime < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), * as status.  You might need something other than CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, I haven't tested.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this..**

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_check BEFORE UPDATE ON account
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.amount < 0 THEN
SET NEW.amount = 0;
ELSEIF NEW.amount > 100 THEN
SET NEW.amount = 100;
END IF;
END;
```

Refer:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html
      http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to help you if we dont really understand the problem you are trying to solve... its a bit of a shot in the dark but how about

```
Update tablename
set status = 1 
where TimeInColumn = ThisTime
```

Comment: actually i want to make a real time application. it's like rent something. when endtime = current time. then automatically status = 1.
thanks for your example but, if just like that i already know. my problem is how to make it AUTOmacally changing.