# automatically add current timestamp when queried

Tags: mysql, timestamp

So whenever  user queries table , I add current timestamp in lastmodified column manually like below.

```
SELECT * FROM  `table` WHERE `ID`=10
INSERT INTO `table` (`lastmodified`) VALUES ('$timestamp') WHERE `ID`=10;
```

Is there anyway I create a column which updates the column with current timestamp whenever I use `select` to that particular row ? or if its not possible how to combine both of the queries above to single..

Comment: You mean for every select it should update the column to the current timestamp ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty : exactly ....

Comment: a select only reads the content so lastmodified is inappropriate for update or insert statements you can create a trigger

Comment: or simply specify it as an `on update current_timestamp` field

Comment: From my purely theoretical point of view an UPDATE should ideally be able to return exactly what a SELECT can return (because in most cases you can even see/get the number of rows affected by an UPDATE). But this seems dependent on database/driver implementation and it just might be the case that most (if not all) db providers don't choose to return rows affected by an update (i would guess for performance reasons as well - the update syntax is different so you would have to return entire rows for something that should be ultra fast).

Comment: possible duplicate of [can i launch a trigger on select statement in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137935/can-i-launch-a-trigger-on-select-statement-in-mysql)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137935/can-i-launch-a-trigger-on-select-statement-in-mysql