# mysql : auto update date on select row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on PHP/MySQL and I'm trying to make my time auto update if a row is selected.

Here is the SQL query I'm using and trying to make it auto update in same time without adding `UPDATE`:

MySQL table (I want `Last_Selected_Time` to update on row select)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `accounts` (
  `Username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Last_Selected_Time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  primary key(Username)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;
```

PHP Code segments:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts where Username = 'test'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot do this in MySQL.  You *could* wrap all the data access queries in a stored procedure, but this useful functionality is missing.

Comment: oh, too bad i wish i could do that to optimize my codes to run faster

Comment: What did you hope to utilise it for?

Comment: @Jeemusu . . . I, for one, would sometimes love to have the functionality of being able to audit which users have seen which records.  Unfortunately, this is not functionality provided by relational databases, without a lot of work.

Comment: @Abdullah I'd expect a function that performs an `UPDATE` each time a `SELECT` is performed would have the opposite effect and make your code slower - in general reading from a db is fast, writing to it is slow.

Answer (score 0):

That's sounds like a trigger that you should use but unfortunately you can't do that for a select. Instead, you can do that using a stored procedure: check this answer: [can i launch a trigger on select statement in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137935/can-i-launch-a-trigger-on-select-statement-in-mysql)