# Whenever MySQL query is hit database table then one database field will update value (counter)

Tags: mysql

When a database table is queried (`select` only) then one field (here the `view` column) value will increase like the counter. Is it possible in MySQL without any server-side language (like PHP)?

[image: 1st Query on this table]

[image: 2nd Query on this table]

Comment: Nope, not possible.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6137935/1169798

Comment: if trigger not working with select then I have to use server side program. Thanks, everyone.