# MySQL select statement manipulation

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MySQL with the below structure:

```
+=================+================+================+=================+
| Value to search | start time     | endtime        | value to return |
+=================+================+================+=================+
| Value A.        | some date/time | some date/time | value 1.        |
| Value B.        | some date/time | some date/time | Value 2.        |
| Value C.        | some date/time | some date/time | value 3.        |
| Value A.        | some date/time | some date/time | value 4.        |
+===================================================+=================+
```

The value to search is not unique, it will be a unique token assigned for a specific time (start and end time).

When sending a query to MySQL, the querying system can only send a simple JDBC query (select valueToSearch, valueToReturn from table/view).

Now what I need to do is to search the table above with a query like: `select valueToReturn from myTable/myView where ( someDateTime < endTime AND someDateTime > startTime AND valueToSearch == value)`

My first option was to create a view which has a key value constructed by merging the valueToSearch with the epoch value for every second between the start and end time, but as a result a simple table row will eventually become 86400 rows, this will be extremely inefficien and will inflate the database size 86400 times.

Now my question is:
How can I send a query to the MySQL database with a merged value (valueToSearch_someDateTime) and then make MySQL manipulate the received query and search for valueToSearch where ( endTime > someDateTime AND startTime < someDateTime) and return the relevant valueToReturn

Thanks for your help.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has a function called [now()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html), so your view can look like

```
CREATE VIEW myView AS SELECT valueToSearch,valueToReturn 
FROM myTable WHERE now() < endTime AND now() > startTime;
```

**EDIT:** Additional view with a parameter from a different table, with exactly one row for the pair valueToSearch and searchTime. Which should be updated/inserted before using the myView2.

```
CREATE VIEW myView2 AS SELECT t1.valueToSearch,t1.valueToReturn
FROM myTable t1,paramTable t2 WHERE t1.valueToSearch = t2.valueToSearch
AND t2.searchTime < t1.endtime AND t2.searchTime > startTime;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Myonara, but I am afraid this is not what I am looking for. The sent dateTime used in query can be any dateTime and not necessarily now. Also is there a way to make MySQL create the query you proposed as a triggered action when it receives a simple query (I.e select valueToSearch_myDateTime from table1)? Thanks

Comment: You should focus on the jdbc/odbc drivers, because only a simple query without a where-clause is not the standard behaviour. I edit my answer above to add another view/query with a parameter from a different table.

Comment: There is no trigger on SELECT, see this [Stackoverflow-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137935/can-i-launch-a-trigger-on-select-statement-in-mysql).