# How to increment the number in row by 1 every time it appears in select query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one particular requirement to increase the number by 1 every time the row appears into the "SELECT * ..." query in MySQL DB.

For example,

Users table:

```
ID   | Name     | Count
1    | John     | 5
2    | Harry    | 3
3    | Herman   | 4
```

Now, If I run the select query like,

```
SELECT 'Name' FROM 'Users' WHERE ID=2;
```

It should return the result of the query and increase the number in the 'Count' column of the second row by 1. Like below:

```
ID   | Name     | Count
1    | John     | 5
2    | Harry    | 4
3    | Herman   | 4
```

I know it may require me to alter my query. It will be a great help if anyone can help me with the query.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6138098/3636601

Comment: I'm guessing you have some front end process in addition to mysql - if so that may be where to capture this.

Comment: just run update query next to select

Comment: This cannot be solved as a query. Create according stored procedure.

Comment: You can simply prepend your SELECT with UPDATE like `UPDATE users SET count = count + 1 WHERE id IN (SELECT id ....)`

Comment: @IVOGELOV Thanks for the query. The query looks like it will be able to update the row. However, I want to get the name of the Users along with this update query. Something like, SELECT + UPDATE.

Comment: SQL does not support multiple operations - only one operation at a time, either SELECT or INSERT or UPDATE or DELETE. If you really need more operations in a combination - you will have to switch MySQL with PostgreSQL and then use UPDATE with a RETURNING clause (not supported by MySQL) inside a CTE (common table expression) in order to then SELECT the updated rows from the CTE output.

Comment: @Jens Thanks for the suggestion. Your solution would surely work in general scenarios. Where I want to implement it is a very specific scenario and I will not be able to use the stored procedures and triggers. It must be SELECT + UPDATE in a single query.

Comment: @Akina Thanks for the suggestion. As mentioned in the above comment, I will not be able to use the stored procedure + triggers.

Comment: @P.Salmon Thanks. But that will not work in my case. :)

Comment: @IVOGELOV Ohh is it? I am not sure about this one. I will surely look into. Thank you very much for the details.

Answer (score 0):

what about ROW_NUMBER() function?

```
SELECT 'Name', ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Name) FROM 'Users' WHERE ID=2;
```

Comment: Hi, This will not work for me, as I need to store the count in the table.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Okay, I think I'm starting to get what you mean. If you are using database, which supports it (postgresql for example), then my next suggestion would be to look into 'UPDATE ... RETURNING' statement. You can update row, while returning a value of such a row. If you are using MariaDB (10.5+), you can use INSERT..RETURNING. Something like:

INSERT INTO Users (ID, Name, Count) 
SELECT ID, Name, Count + 1 FROM Users u2 WHERE pes_cislo = 4
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Users.Count=u2.Count + 1
RETURNING Name